# Needs an explanation difference between "like to go..." and "like going..."

Tags: infinitives

The question is : Peter _____ running in the evening.

The answer can be either *likes to go*, and *likes going*.

I assumed that both answers mean the same thing, however they could be interpreted slightly differently.

This is the question on the workbook about "to + infinitive" on unit 1, and I am working on it right now.

Should I answer *likes to go* instead of *likes going* because this unit talks about to + infinitive or should I discuss this with my teacher?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to discuss this question with your teacher, since neither of the two possible answers is "correct" unless the adjunct "_this evening_" is removed.

Comment: See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381858/start-gerund-vs-start-infinitive-is-there-a-subtle-tense-difference) and [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/try-to-save-or-try-saving) although I agree the original sentence is wrong whatever you put in the blank.

Comment: You would need "like*s*" for the 3rd person singular.

Comment: You could say "Peter *would* like to go running this evening". Or "Peter likes to go running *in* the evening".

Comment: Although the 'like to V-phrase' and 'like + ing-clause' can be subtly different in connotation, I can't pick any difference up with your example. // I've removed the inappropriate fixed time adverbial.

Comment: Now that the sentence has been changed from _this evening_ to _in the evening_, both versions are valid. Different shades of meaning - 'likes to go' = often goes, 'likes going' = enjoys the activity.